# How to merge a nested List into a simple List using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` which looks as follows:

```
List<List<Class2>> list = new ArrayList<>();

List<Class2> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add(new Class2(new Class3()));
l1.add(new Class2(new Class3()));
l1.add(new Class2(new Class3()));
list.add(l1);

List<Class2> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
l2.add(new Class2(new Class3()));
l2.add(new Class2(new Class3()));
l2.add(new Class2(new Class3()));
list.add(l2);
```

How can I convert the `List` `list` into a `List<Class3>` using the Java 8 Stream API?

Comment: Where are your attempts?

Comment: No attempts yet, except the brute-force method where I iterated over the list and extracted the `Class3` object by myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are passing to the `Class2` constructor an instance of `Class3`, I'm assuming `Class2` has a `Class3` member with a getter (lets call the getter `getClass3()`).

Based on this assumption, you can do the following to get a `List<Class3>` of all the `Class3` members of all the `Class2` members of all the lists contained in `list` :

```
List<Class3> listOf3 = 
    list.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream) // convert a Stream<List<Class2>> to Stream<Class2>
        .map(Class2::getClass3) // convert a Stream<Class2> to Stream<Class3>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect to a List<Class3>
```